# Php: Testing multiple concurrent browser sessions

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am marking a online examination web portal for my college. I am using code Igniter for it. Recently one staff member told me that you need to optimized your code as I would fail if 100 student will give test concurrently.

I tested it with 2 user and I am having only 2 devices. Its working fine.

My question is, Can I automate the process for test purpose? Like wise 100 user get created by the testing tool and 100 concurrent process starts. What I do with a single user, same tool must do with 100 user.

Any suggestion how I can optimized my portal for concurrent sessions.

Comment: There are tons of testing tools which can spawn concurrent sessions for testing.  That being said, this question is reading as a tool recommendation question which is off topic on SO.

Comment: In general PHP + CI on any reasonable server (even a PC server or raspberry pi) should work fine with 100 client access. If you really afraid reaching such problem, please draft how students interact during the exam and what HTTP GET / POST involved.

Comment: I searched over internet to find a appropriate tool to test my site. But I was unable to find a  good one. Kindly suggest me some tool.